# Orders of elements in alternating group $A_{10}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I know $A_{10}$ has elements of order 1,3,5,7,9,15,21 where the odd numbers arise form single cycles being even and 15, 21 come from $lcm(3,5)$ and $lcm(3,7)$ respectively. I'm not sure how to justify the remaining orders of 2,4,6,8,10,12. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I dont understand the question. $A_{10}$ only has odd ordered elements.

Comment: I found a page that says the even ordered elements are in $A_{10}$ which is why I'm asking.

Comment: An element of $S_n$ is even if and only if, when written as a product of disjoint cycles, an even number of those are odd cycles (equivalently, have even length).  So it's fine to have (e.g.) a 2-cycle as long as there's also another 2-cycle, or a 4-cycle, etc.  P Vanchinathan's answer gives some good examples.

Comment: What's the order of $(1\ 2)(3\ 4)$?

Answer (score 4):

12=lcm(2,3,4), and the perm has cycle structure 10=1+2+3+4, is even.

10 = lcm(2,2,5) and the perm has cycle structure 10= 1+2+2+5 is even.

To get an element of order 2, e.g., take two disjoint transpositions
Others can be done similarly.

Comment: Could you explain how the element of order 2 is in $A_{10}$. Wouldn't a cycle or length two have odd order?

Comment: I said a permutation that is a product of two disjoint transpositions: individually a 2-cycle is odd, but a product of two disjoint two 2-cycles will be odd, and of order 2.

Comment: I meant product will be even. Too late to edit my comment.